# Curl bad request

Tags: curl, bad-request

I investigated php-javascript transifex client, at https://github.com/fazakis/transifex-javascript-client/blob/master/api , it is one of a good example. I am preparing java client but i am always getting bad request for put and posts

This GET reqest is perfect :

```
curl -i -L --user gccster:test -X GET http://www.transifex.com/api/2/project/demoproject1/resource/test/translation/el/string/bff3b5b0513a5e4821f649ffcca93069/
```

But This PUT Request returns Bad Request

```
curl -i -L --user gccster:test -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"translation": "nick"}' http://www.transifex.com/api/2/project/demoproject1/resource/test/translation/el/string/bff3b5b0513a5e4821f649ffcca93069/
```

What can be the problem ?

Comment: no idea about this api, but you're using what looks to be an API key as provided by that example. If that `bff3b....` stuff is an access key, then that's almost certainly NOT going to be a valid key for actual usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc B , it is md5 of concatenation of key and context. There is no api key for this saas. If it is not correct, GET request's response would be "Not Found", but it returns answer: `{

    "comment": "",
    "context": [
        "This is a Content",
        ""
    ],
    "key": "Footer here",
    "reviewed": false,
    "user": "gccster",
    "pluralized": false,
    "source_string": "Footer here",
    "position": 1,
    "translation": "nick2",
    "last_update": "2012-11-11T17:48:43.881",
    "occurrences": null

}`

Comment: I don't know the cause but my java HTTPClient client is working now. Thanks.